# Notification service ( Spring boot + Kafka)

Tags: java, spring, apache-kafka, quartz-scheduler

We have got a notification requirement.

User logins to website. He will have multiple options regarding notification.

1. Add a remainder (we have to send out a mail at scheduled time and If user is already logged in then we have to display the notification in website, If no then we have to show all the unread notifications when he logs in)
2. update future remainder
3. Delete a future remainder.

My team is very much particular to spring boot and Kafka.

My approach:

1. Implement a micro service which will do following operations

   - Adds a remainder (/add)
   - updates a remainder(/update)
   - Deletes a remainder (/delete)
   - sends multiple  remainders (we will publish remainders in 2 Kafkas. One is used to trigger mail, other is used for displaying remainders in UI) (/send)
2. implement a quartz job which runs every 1 minute , reads the remainders of next one min from db and calls , call /send end point of other service

is my approach is good enough or is there any better approach I can follow?

No of end customers : around 100 000
Thanks in advance

Comment: Is *My team is very much particular* some sort of local saying? At least I don't understand its' meaning.

Answer (score 1):

If my understanding is correct, apart from your Microservice for your orchestration, you would be building two more Kafka Consumers, one for trigger email and another one is for displaying remainders in UI.

This sounds a good design and you guys want to introduce Kafka ecosystem in your project, you can do much more with Kafka underlying features, and you won't be having any operational overheads down the line. But you can reconsider your design option, because your business logic can be easily implemented using a traditional Spring Boot web application too.